# Laravel: object unable to access its properties

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have a function which returns an object with one of it's parameters set to some certain value:

```
public function search($jobsdone, $date)
{
    foreach ($jobsdone as $jd) {
        if ($jd->date_worked == $date) return $jd;
    }
}
```

Printing search($jobsdone, $key) yields such results:

```
object(JobDone)#378 (19) {
  ...
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3593)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(13)
    ["object_id"]=>
    int(99)
    ["job_id"]=>
    int(130)
    ["date_worked"]=>
    string(10) "2013-10-01"
    ["min_from"]=>
    int(780)
    ["min_to"]=>
    int(1080)
  }
  ...
}
```

However, if I want to print out search($jobsdone, $key)->id, all I get is an error message of:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `search` function doesn't always return an object. Therefore, you get error `Trying to get property of non-object` whenever your search couldn't find a `$jobdone` object.

Comment: Can't believe I've spent an hour not noticing this. Thank you.